# Deploying Apache Beam pipeline on Alibaba cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, alibaba-cloud

I am new to Alibaba Cloud and I have an Apache Beam application running on Google Cloud Dataflow.
Now I want to deploy the same apache beam pipeline to Alibaba Cloud.
I am seeking help on how/what setups are needed to run an apache beam pipeline in Alibaba Cloud?
Is there a resource in Alibaba that is equivalent to Google Cloud Platform Dataflow?

Answer (score 0):

You may try Alibaba DataStudio, in the Data Works section of the Alibaba Cloud Console as it is similar to Data Flow from google cloud .

You can drag and drop nodes to create a workflow, collaborate, integrate with other AC products etc.

Here is how you can create workflow: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/85554.htm?spm=a2c63.l28256.a3.31.591c5b5aLHvJ68

It is not based on Apache Beam, but I believe that it will be available very soon.

Hope this will help to get idea about your needs, and what is offered right now.